# Preventing an HTML element from inheriting parent spin animation

Tags: html, css, webkit

I've added a "loading" spinner to a web page by using animations, as follows:

```
<style>

.spinner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -70px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

</style>

<div class="spinner"></div>
```

Which is great. But I'd now like to have the text "Loading" fixed in place in the center of the spinner. I tried to do this by using relative positioning:

```
.loader {
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

<div class="spinner">
    <div class="loader>LOADING</div>
</div>
```

But this inherits the parent animation. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3tvuzu0s/) of the thing going wrong.

I've tried adding the following to the `.loader` class to try and fix this:

```
animation: none !important;

animation: spin 2s linear infinite reverse;
```

Neither works.

Is this fixable? Or am I better off trying to use fixed positioning on the text too rather than nesting the `div` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also try putting it inside another container and reversing the spin on the container

```css
.loader {
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

.spinner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -70px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

.holder {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite reverse;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="loader">
      LOADING ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If you look at the original question, you'll see I did try using the animation in reverse, but without an extra "holder" element which you've used to make it work. Can you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: It can work without the `holder`, but you will have to move the `transform origin` of the `loader` to the `transform origin` of the `spinner`, with can be a little tricky to determine but with a similarly sized holder sub-parent, the axis of rotation aka `transform origin` is exactly same as the spinner and it easily negates the "motion". In the end it's all about transform origin. But with a sub-parent, you won't have to worry about positioning the `loader` anymore

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```css
    .loader {
      width: 120px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      height: auto;
    }
    .holder {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -70px;
      margin-top: -50px;
    }
    .spinner {
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes spin {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="holder">
      <div class="spinner">
      </div>
      <div class="loader">
        LOADING ...
      </div>
    </div>
```